# Long RichTextBlock inside a ScrollViewer, how to implement virtualization?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uwp

Currently, I'm showing a really long text inside a `RichTextBlock` inside a `ScrollViewer`.

The problem is since `ScrollViewer` doesn't support virtualization, loading the page takes a few seconds, and changing font size (it's an option for the user) takes a long time and may even cause the app to crash.

One solution came to my mind is to break `RichTextBlock` to a number of `RichTextBlock`s inside a `ListView` (which supports Virtualization).

But this approach has a little problem. Let's say I show each 500 lines of text inside a `RichTextBlock`. Now, the user may want to select and copy some text; while it'll work well in most cases, but he'll never be able to select lines 498 to 503, because they are in two separate `RichTextBlock`s.

Is there any way to fix the text selection issue in this approach? Or can you suggest a better way for implementing virtualization?

Comment: The most reliable solution would be to find a new way to present the data that doesn't involve a scroll viewer containing other scrollviewer controls (like the rich text edit).

Comment: @WiredPrairie `RichTextBlock` doesn't have a `ScrollViewer` inside it.

Comment: The `RichTextBox` does ... which is what I thought you meant when I read your question. :)  Honestly, this problem has come up many times in the last few years as the tech you're using is originally based on Silverlight, which had the same issue. There's never been a particularly satisfying solution other than to design a different user experience where this can't be an issue.

Comment: @WiredPrairie I was thinking about using a `RichEditBox` instead, but seems that it doesn't support xaml text and I have to create it in plan (*scary/ugly*) rtf. Am I missing something?

Comment: What kind of content do you have?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Some Persian poetry. it's just normal text but text alignment might be different in different verses (left, right, center), also I might want to add a margin from left or right to some of centered verses too.

Comment: You might want to consider embedding a WebView and inject the content as HTML. You can't put it in a scroll viewer though (as the webview is height limited and performs poorly and uses a **lot** of system resources if it exceeds screen height).

Comment: @WiredPrairie That was what I tried first, but experienced issues with handling swiping. Although then I replaced those with a `Pivot` later (after switching to `RickTextBlock`). And now I checked and it seems swiping a `WebView` inside `Pivot` works fine. Maybe I'll consider switching back to HTML method. And I don't need to put it inside a `ScrollViewer`. WebView has something like `ScrollViewer` inside it afterall. Thanks :)

Comment: @WiredPrairie I just saw that `WebView` doesn't work well with a `Pivot` on the phone. (it's ok on touch PC but not in phone). So using `WebView` is not an option unfortunately :(

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @Maryam Unfortunately no. At last I used the approach described in the question and ignored that little problem with it.